# 24 Hour Reminder [JavaScript, Cookies]

Tags: javascript, date, cookies

I am having trouble making a script to reminder people to click on a link every 24 hours.
I need a script that will create a cookie after clicking 'done' with the current date, then after visiting the page, if the date has passed show the reminder again, if the date has not passed, then do nothing.
Any ideas on where to start, or any sample code I could use?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First master the cookie basics in JavaScript and then ... look at these libs

- [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)
- [Javascript Cookie Library](http://code.google.com/p/cookies/)